# Problem linking on cross compile to ARM

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to get a "Hello World" application compiled for an ARM target. I'm cross compiling using gcc on Ubuntu/VMWare. If I compile for the host machine, it works fine. When I compile for the target, I get this error:

```
/root/picokernel/toolchain/arm-eabi/lib/libcs3hosted.a(hosted-sbrk.o): In function `_sbrk':
sbrk.c:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `__cs3_heap_limit'
/root/picokernel/toolchain/arm-eabi/lib/libcs3hosted.a(hosted-sbrk.o):(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `__cs3_heap_start'
make: *** [HelloWorld] Error 1
```

So I think I need to link something in - perhaps my toolchain does not have the right libs? I was able to build the kernel, so I thought it was complete. Thanks! [This is the target board.](http://arm.mini-box.com/index.php?title=Main_Page) - runs Angstrom or Android.

**makefile**:

```
CC=$(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
LD=$(CROSS_COMPILE)ld 
CROSS_LIB1=/root/picokernel/toolchain/arm-eabi/lib 
CROSS_LIB2=/root/picokernel/toolchain/lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.2.1
CFLAGS=-Wall
LDFLAGS= -L$(CROSS_LIB1) -L$(CROSS_LIB2) -lc -lcs3hosted -lg -lgcc --entry main
HelloWorld: HelloWorld.o 
    $(LD) HelloWorld.o $(LDFLAGS)
```

clean:
    rm -f HelloWorld HelloWorld.o

**program**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   printf("Hello World\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Embedded Arm with or without Linux kernel? Whitout a kernel you have to implement puts yourself.

Comment: Thanks - I should have noted this comes with a kernel - I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - finally worked this out, picked up a toolchain from the source here:

http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/release1803

Hello World works great! Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 2):

I gotta say, this is suspicious: `-nostdlib`

How about **not** using this flag?

Comment: Thanks Karl - removing -nostdlib results in the following error, which I think is expected, as the ARM binaries so not use the default crt0. /root/picokernel/toolchain/bin/arm-eabi-gcc -lc -lgcc --entry main   HelloWorld.o   -o HelloWorld
/root/picokernel/toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.2.1/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/ld: crt0.o: No such file: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Have you tried adding `--sysroot=/root/picokernel/toolchain` to the command line?

Comment: Do you have a C++ compiler for that arch?

Comment: Ok - just tried sysroots, got this: this linker was not configured to use sysroots. And I think the compiler is ok, it builds the kernel.

Comment: To compile the example, you need to have `crt0`. Search it inside the toolchain. Do you have it?

Comment: There's no crt0 for this arch - it does have crtn.o, crti.o, crtbegin.o, crtend.o - thanks!

Comment: Hi Karl - I've updated the makefile I'm using - I think I'm getting closer, and it looks like something to fo with the CodeSourcery toolchain. I'm going there next, Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

The kernel does not use the C runtime library since the library does many—if not most—things not permitted by kernel code like file i/o and allocating memory.

Normally, you don't have to specify a library at all.  `gcc` assumes the right thing.  Try removing setting `LDFLAGS` altogether:  I bet it works better.

Comment: Thanks - but the -nostdlib is required, or you get "crt0.o" No such file error, see above comment. Leaving off the LDFLAGS works great if I target the host system, but not when cross-compiling

Answer (score 0):

Does the toolchain you are using have a library called "lcs3arm" ? If so, try adding that to the list. You can also try "-lcs3" itself

Out of interest, which version of GCC are you using here? (i.e. which CodeSourcery release)

Comment: Oh, and also try specifying the target architecture and/or CPU type on the command line to the compiler (e.g. --march=armv7-a)

Comment: Thanks - both libs are there - adding them to the link did not help. the architecture is ARCH=arm. If I leave out the printf, the code links and runs on the target - I just have to figure out which lib to link against.